# What can a scammer do if I give them my fake email ID?

Tags: email, security, phishing

I received an SMS today about my mobile number having won 30 million from the BMW company, and all I had to do to claim it was to send my name, address, contact number, age and occupation to bmw34681@gmail.com.

Now there's a person named [James Veitch](https://www.ted.com/talks/james_veitch_this_is_what_happens_when_you_reply_to_spam_email) who encourages people to reply to such emails using a newly created pseudonym email ID, just for the fun of it.

I've heard of [email tracking pixels](http://smallbusiness.chron.com/set-email-tracking-pixel-49332.html), but wanted to know if in the process of having fun wasting a spammers time, would it be possible for them to actually find out who I am or where I am or be able to do anything malicious, even if I take care to only give them incorrect/fake information the whole time?

In short: Is it safe to play games with such scum?

Comment: They might be able to take your first born child so use caution.... lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The headers of your email could include your IP address, which gives out a little bit of information about you (general physical location and ISP) and could be correlated with additional information online (if your IP address appears elsewhere, linked to you). Depending on how you set up and use your email account they could [also see your real email address](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/4469/how-to-use-gmails-send-mail-as-with-another-gmail-account-through-smtp-withou).

They could send tracking pixels in any emails back to you; if you loaded that pixel they'd get your IP address and browser information (OS and version). If you visit a web page they send you and run some javascript (in the background, you wouldn't know about it, which is why you should typically browse the Internet with javascript disabled) they could get additional information about your computer, possibly enough to [uniquely identify you](https://panopticlick.eff.org/) if you visit again or visit another site they own.

Just because all that information is available to them, doesn't mean they know it's there or that they'd take advantage of it. You could mitigate all this by running in a VM through TOR, etc., but you'd have to be pretty disciplined to ensure *no* real information about you ever leaks out. It's pretty easy to make a mistake when using this sort of setup. You'd be spending a lot of time just to mess with someone.

Answer (score 0):

i dont think a scamemer would waste his time tracking somebody down, they are way too lazy to work in order to earn money so they have to steal/scam i hardly believe they will actually spend a dime on tracking you down or hunting you down.
if they got your cellphone number would be easier to track you with the proper resources of course than tracking you by email and ip addresses. anyway, when you send an email to the email they gave you they will receive hundreds of emails from people they sent the same sms so there is no way that they can link your phone number to the email you send because they wont make a separate email account for every sms they send. they just massively send that sms to hundreds of cellphone numbers.

that unless you reply back the sms saying that email account you will send the information he asked from.

so if you are really paranoid dont let him know ur phone number and also use a proxy for sending emails.

i would not worry. they are probably not even in your country.